# Snippet tool that is used in WWDC2010 videos

Tags: xcode, code-snippets, wwdc

Does anyone know the code snippet tool that was used in some of the WWDC2010 videos?

It seems that the the tool allows us to create snippets of code which can be labeled.  This tool also allow us to click and drag the label to Xcode code editor window to paste the code with the formatting intact.

Any lead on this tool/utility?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for [DemoMonkey](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/DemoMonkey/Introduction/Intro.html). I can't get the cool eskimo icon they have, though.